# How do I get hundred percent code coverage with my unit testing on this component and access the else part?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have no idea how to access the remaining line of code. I simply need to get a full code coverage. Checking if the function has been called (toHaveBeenCalled() ) will also do.

Pasting in the TypeScript file and my Spec file. My current code-coverage is as follows

TOTAL: 7 SUCCESS

==================== Coverage summary ========================

Statements   : 87.5% ( 35/40 )

Branches     : 100% ( 10/10 )

Functions    : 75% ( 6/8 )

Lines        : 86.11% ( 31/36 )

================================================================================

[image]

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```js
import { AuthKeywords } from './../_models/common.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AppService } from './../app.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/api';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  constructor(public router: Router, public appService: AppService,
    public cookieService: CookieService, public confirmationService: ConfirmationService) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    const token = this.cookieService.get(AuthKeywords.TOKEN);
    if (token && !this.tokenExpired(token)) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      return of(this.isLoggedIn);  
    } else {
      this.appService.confirmButtonLabel = 'Login';
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'You are not logged in, Please login to Traders Desktop',
        accept: () => {
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
          window.location.replace(environment.traders_desktop);
          return of(this.isLoggedIn);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  public tokenExpired(token: string) {
    const expiry = (JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))).exp;
    return (Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1000)) >= expiry;
  }
}
```

**auth-guard.service.gen.spec.ts**

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppService } from './../app.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Confirmation, ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/api';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';
import {} from 'jasmine';


describe('AuthGuardService', () => {
  let service: AuthGuardService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const appServiceStub = () => ({ confirmButtonLabel: {} });
    const routerStub = () => ({});
    const cookieServiceStub = () => ({ get: token => ({}) });
    const confirmationServiceStub = () => ({ confirm: object => ({}) });


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthGuardService,
        { provide: AppService, useFactory: appServiceStub },
        { provide: Router, useFactory: routerStub },
        { provide: CookieService, useFactory: cookieServiceStub },
        { provide: ConfirmationService, useFactory: confirmationServiceStub }
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(AuthGuardService);
    const token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRpbiI6dHJ1ZSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ5YXNoLW1pc2hyYSIsImxvZ2luX3RpbWUiOjE2MDE0NTMxNDAsIkxBU1RfQUNUSVZJVFkiOjE2MDE0NTMxNDAsInN1cGVyX3VzZXIiOnRydWUsImlzcyI6IlRyYWRlVmlzaW9uMjAyMC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJDaGFydElRVmVyaWZpY2F0aW9uIiwiYXVkIjoieWFzaC1taXNocmEiLCJleHAiOjE2MDE1Mzk1NDB9.6S2cIrflTPRdTjXIaYaFcb2J5LrTa9-yqzfVVuNC85M';
    service.tokenExpired(token)
  });

  it('can load instance', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`isLoggedIn has default value`, () => {
    expect(service.isLoggedIn).toEqual(false);
  });

  it('checks button label value', () => {
    const appServiceStub: AppService = TestBed.get(AppService)
    expect(appServiceStub.confirmButtonLabel).toBeTruthy();
    expect(appServiceStub.confirmButtonLabel).toBeDefined()
  })

  describe('token expiration', () => {
    it('checks token expiration', () => {
      const cookieServiceStub: CookieService = TestBed.get(CookieService);
      const confirmationServiceStub: ConfirmationService = TestBed.get(ConfirmationService);
      const component: AuthGuardService = TestBed.get(AuthGuardService);
      
      spyOn(component, 'tokenExpired').and.callThrough();
      const token:string = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRpbiI6dHJ1ZSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ5YXNoLW1pc2hyYSIsImxvZ2luX3RpbWUiOjE2MDE0NTMxNDAsIkxBU1RfQUNUSVZJVFkiOjE2MDE0NTMxNDAsInN1cGVyX3VzZXIiOnRydWUsImlzcyI6IlRyYWRlVmlzaW9uMjAyMC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJDaGFydElRVmVyaWZpY2F0aW9uIiwiYXVkIjoieWFzaC1taXNocmEiLCJleHAiOjE2MDE1Mzk1NDB9.6S2cIrflTPRdTjXIaYaFcb2J5LrTa9-yqzfVVuNC85M'
      component.tokenExpired(token)

      expect(component.tokenExpired).toHaveBeenCalled();
      
    })
  })

  describe('checks canActivate Observable', () => {
    it('checks inside if condition', () => {
      const component: AuthGuardService = TestBed.get(AuthGuardService);
      spyOn(component, 'tokenExpired')
      let tempToken = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRpbiI6dHJ1ZSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ5YXNoLW1pc2hyYSIsImxvZ2luX3RpbWUiOjE2MDE0NTMxNDAsIkxBU1RfQUNUSVZJVFkiOjE2MDE0NTMxNDAsInN1cGVyX3VzZXIiOnRydWUsImlzcyI6IlRyYWRlVmlzaW9uMjAyMC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJDaGFydElRVmVyaWZpY2F0aW9uIiwiYXVkIjoieWFzaC1taXNocmEiLCJleHAiOjE2MDE1Mzk1NDB9.6S2cIrflTPRdTjXIaYaFcb2J5LrTa9-yqzfVVuNC85M'
      component.tokenExpired(tempToken);
      component.canActivate().subscribe(token => {
        expect(token).toBe(true);
      });  
    })

    it('checks inside else condition', () => {

      const component: AuthGuardService = TestBed.get(AuthGuardService);
      const appServiceStub: AppService = TestBed.get(AppService);
      
      spyOn(component, 'tokenExpired').and.returnValue(true)
      service.canActivate()
      expect(appServiceStub.confirmButtonLabel).toBe('Login')
    })

    it('checks accept inside else condition', () => {
      const component: AuthGuardService = TestBed.get(AuthGuardService);
      const appServiceStub: AppService = TestBed.get(AppService);
      const confirmationServiceStub: ConfirmationService = TestBed.get(ConfirmationService)
      let param: Confirmation = {message: 'Test Message', accept: () => {return false}}


      spyOn(component, 'tokenExpired').and.returnValue(true)

      spyOn(confirmationServiceStub, 'confirm')
      
      })
    })

});
```

Comment: Which bit of code do you think the code coverage is missing?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - I cannot access the else part inside the canActivate observable. Put a picture for your reference.

Comment: I clearly don't understand how it works.  You are using exactly the same token in the test for the if part and the test for the else part.  But the token for the else part should be different because it needs to be expired.  Right?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: I am supposed to set token to be null to enter the else part. How do I do that?

Comment: The if statement says that the token can be null or that it can be expired to get into the else part.  So I assumed you were trying to create an expired token to get into the else part.  To do that you just need an expired token.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: I am trying to get into accept property of Confirmation Service. How can I access those three lines?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: Would be more than grateful if you could help me with these unvisited lines

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part here is that the code you need to test is in a callback function (`accept()`) that, in a normal runtime scenario, would be invoked by the `ConfirmationService` (presumably when a user clicks a button). However, since you're mocking the `ConfirmationService` for your test, you need to invoke that callback function yourself in your test.

Looking at your code, you can see that the `ConfirmationService#confirm` method is passed a confirmation object with a `message` property and the `accept` callback function whose logic you need to test:

```js
this.confirmationService.confirm({
  message: 'You are not logged in, Please login to Traders Desktop',
  accept: () => {
    // you need to test the business logic in this function
  }
});
```

You need to get a hold of that passed-in confirmation object so you can invoke its `accept` method yourself to trigger the business logic inside and verify its effects.

To do that, you can create a Spy for the `ConfirmationService#confirm` method that `callsFake` a function that you control in your test. That function will then be passed the confirmation object so you can manually invoke its `accept` method, like this:

```js
spyOn(confirmationServiceStub, 'confirm').and.callFake(confirmation => {
  confirmation.accept() // <---- manually invoke the accept callback
})
```

Here's what the final test would look like:

```js
it('checks accept inside else condition', () => {
  const component: AuthGuardService = TestBed.get(AuthGuardService);
  const confirmationServiceStub: ConfirmationService = TestBed.get(ConfirmationService)
  const locationStub: Location = TestBed.get(Location)

  spyOn(component, 'tokenExpired').and.returnValue(true)
  const locationSpy = spyOn(locationStub, 'replaceState').and.stub();

  spyOn(confirmationServiceStub, 'confirm').and.callFake(confirmation => {
    expect(confirmation.message).toContain('You are not logged in')

    confirmation.accept() // <---- manually invoke the accept callback
  })

  component.canActivate().subscribe(token => {
    expect(token).toBe(false)
    expect(locationSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('//traders_desktop.org')
  });  
})
```

Before you do that, though, you need to fix your `canActivate` method because the `else` block is not returning an Observable like it needs to. In fact, isn't returning anything, it's just calling `this.confirmationService.confirm()`.

What you need to do is wrap the `this.confirmationService.confirm()` call inside an Observable that you return, and have that Observable emit when the `accept` callback is invoked. Something like this:

```js
} else {
  this.appService.confirmButtonLabel = 'Login';

  return new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber) => { // <--- you need to return an Observable here
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'You are not logged in, Please login to Traders Desktop',
      accept: () => {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        window.location.replace('//traders_desktop.org')
        
        subscriber.next(this.isLoggedIn); // <--- emit from Observable when accept callback is invoked
        subscriber.complete();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-demo-pa39so?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth-guard.service.ts) showing this approach.

You'll notice that I also replaced your reference to `window.location` with Angular's `Location` service so it can be mocked in the unit test (it's also considered a best practice).